# Data Table count non empty rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application allows the user to upload an excel file that by default has 500 line (with a certain structure).

The customer first downloads the empty file as a template and then fills as many lines as he wants.

Then he uploads it to my server and i need to count the non empty lines - remember the template file contains 500 lines by default, but the customer does not always fill all the 500 lines.

This is the "data table", how can I count the filled lines and not the empty lines?

```
dtInvalidCustomers = SessionManager.GetSessionValue<DataTable>(
        Constants.IMPORT_DATATABLE_INVALIDS);
```

Comment: You should state the (unexpected?) result you get from this action.

Answer (score 0):

Why taking 500 lines by default?

The approach i would use if i were you is by **reading directly from the excel file which would return all the records till the last row changed in excel**.

As in your situation according you can loop in one of the following way:-

1) **Looping 500 Rows** :- check if the row is empty and should or not be taken in consideration

2) **Validate Looping** :- if you know that if gaps cant be left in rows then you can check for 1 blank row and if found break the loop.

Hope it helps

Comment: It would be help if you would post a code that do that.
How can i iterate all the rows in the data table (dtInvalidCustomers) and count only the filled ones?

Comment: before giving the code please tell me the list of fields the excel contains? why are you taking 500 lines as default? which fields are necessary to fill

Comment: i am giving the excel with 500 lines because, it's simpler for the user to know that he can add more lines.. It's more for visualization.. the field ` row.ItemArray[2]` must be field .. it's an email